# how to add multiple legends for multiple loops in one plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I have a network of lines where the lines have been added to the network by two for loops. I have colorized the lines of each of loops and now i need to add the legend for those two group of lines. Below is the code that I have written for my network and in the attached image the result is shown

```
figure('name','Distances Comparison with computed uncertainties');

labels = cellstr( num2str([1:SIFT_Length]') ); 

text(SIFT_3D(:,1), SIFT_3D(:,2),SIFT_3D(:,3), labels, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom','FontWeight','bold', 'FontSize', 18, ...
                         'HorizontalAlignment','right')

title('Accepted and Rejected Distances based on distance difference and standard deviation comparison','FontWeight','bold', 'FontSize',18);

hold on
for k = 1:length(Network_lines_Unaccepted(:,1))
 plot3([SIFT_3D(Network_lines_Unaccepted(k,1),1),SIFT_3D(Network_lines_Unaccepted(k,2),1)],...
       [SIFT_3D(Network_lines_Unaccepted(k,1),2),SIFT_3D(Network_lines_Unaccepted(k,2),2)],...
       [SIFT_3D(Network_lines_Unaccepted(k,1),3),SIFT_3D(Network_lines_Unaccepted(k,2),3)],...
       'ro--','MarkerFaceColor',[0 1 1],'MarkerEdgeColor','k', 'LineWidth',2)
end
for k = 1:length(Network_lines_accepted(:,1))
 plot3([SIFT_3D(Network_lines_accepted(k,1),1),SIFT_3D(Network_lines_accepted(k,2),1)],...
       [SIFT_3D(Network_lines_accepted(k,1),2),SIFT_3D(Network_lines_accepted(k,2),2)],...
       [SIFT_3D(Network_lines_accepted(k,1),3),SIFT_3D(Network_lines_accepted(k,2),3)],...
       'go-','MarkerFaceColor',[0 1 1],'MarkerEdgeColor','k', 'LineWidth',1.7)
end
hold off
set(gca, 'XTickLabelMode', 'manual', 'XTickLabel', []);
set(gca, 'YTickLabelMode', 'manual', 'YTickLabel', []);
set(gca, 'ZTickLabelMode', 'manual', 'ZTickLabel', []);
axis off
```

[image]

Now I want to add two legend for green and red lines. does anybody help me that how can I do this?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30029918/1893154) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741311/matlab-graph-plotting-assigning-legend-labels-during-plot) help you?

Comment: @zeeMonkeez, this is my code I don't know how can I add the legend for green and red groups of line

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16742947/1893154), it says how to add legend labels to plots and then display a legend. The only difference is that you probably only want to add the `DisplayName` property to the first plot in each loop.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez, It did not work properly. it make a legend for each lines! but I need only two legends: one for green lines and one for red lines

Comment: @zeeMonkeez, I set 'DisplayName' for each plot but as I told you it shows me a legend for each of lines! for example it shows 15 times green and the rest red in my legend list!! I need only one representative for green lines and one representative for red lines

Comment: I vote to close as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10741311/1893154

Comment: @zeeMonkeez, THX for your solutions but none of them solved my problem. I solved the problem by myself and I put my solution here that maybe helpful for others as well.

Comment: In the for loop, these changes should be done:
     'for k = 1:length(Network_lines_Unaccepted(:,1))'
     'h(1)= plot3(....)'
     'end'
     'hold on;'
     'for k = 1:length(Network_lines_accepted(:,1))'
     ' h(2) =  plot3(...)'
     'end'
     'hold off;'
     'legend(h(1:2),'Rejected line','Accepted line');'
     ......